# Recommandation while using MSOffice 2016 with AbcPdf on Windows Server 2012

Tags: abcpdf, abcpdf9

I'm trying to configure MSOffice 2016(x64) on a Windows Server 2012(x64) to run with ABCPdf 9.1.2.5(x64).

At runtime, the application fails because of this message: `"Failed to get MS Office installation path."`

So far I couldn't find an explicit explanation of why this problem occurs.

The application pool uses the "ApplicationPoolIdentity" (instead of dedicated account) and Office has been installed with an account having Admin privileges.

I also followed recommandation on websupergoo website [link here](http://www.websupergoo.com/support-microsoft-office.htm)

Machine has been restarted after installation, DCOM config has been made accordingly to instructions given (both for folders and launch/activation);

- Is there any way to login as Application Pool user in cmd to run WinWord once ?
- Is there any AppData file to copy from one user to another - like for OpenOffice installation ?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying this kind of configuration, please be aware that highest compatible version with AbcPDF is Office 2013. Office 2016 is compatible from version 10.

Below, answer from support

> The highest version with ABCpdf 9 is Office 2013 - for Office 2016 you
>   would need to upgrade to ABCpdf 10.

Answer (score 0):

Since office was preinstalled on my laptop, i had to reinstall office 365 through the Office app that was already available.. then abcpdf was able to find my installation path